# QComboBox - нет выпадающего списка

Tags: c++, qt

[Скриншот](https://ps.vk.me/c538617/u8164622/docs/dc4383b9dd5c/a.png)

По клику выскакивает такая вот штука, значения получается менять только прокруткой колёсика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Установить QComboBox::maxVisibleItems в ненулевое значение
2. Установить минимальную высоту списка